# How to authenticate and log on to SharePoint 2013 using excel vba

Tags: authentication, vba

I have to fetch data from a file in SharePoint 2013 using VBA and I am mapping the SharePoint site to my network drive and accessing the file. This is working fine when I had already signed in with my Outlook email in to the SharePoint site. But if I am trying this without signing in, I get an error message something like "unable to complete the request because the user was not authenticated". So, I just want to know how can I authenticate myself and logon to SharePoint through VBA before I map the site to a network drive?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the setup, you can try creating a dummy excel file and uploading it to a SharePoint folder.  If you are not authenticate it will either open a browser for you to enter your credentials or just authenticate you if you're passing your windows credentials.